# Loading UEFI compatible software into USB and running it

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, bootable

I have a compiled and linked C file supposedly runnable by a UEFI system as a kernel, and I noticed that using qemu to run it is tedious.

Is there any way of running this code as if it were a BIOS bootloader (inject the raw binaries, perhaps the EFI or the IMG file, into a USB stick and turn on the computer it is connected to)?

Comment: You could have a UEFI system boot from the USB (assuming you conform to the "secure boot" spec). Or, instead of `qemu`, how about running as a VM under `vmware`, `xen`, or `virtualbox`?

Comment: the thing is, what do I run? I have a EFI and an IMG file, and none of them work. VMWare directly goes into the internet OS thing

Comment: I've only used virtualbox, but if you have a bootable image, you can copy it to one of vbox's virtual disks to boot. Or, in vbox's device manager, IIRC, you can map a real device as bootable. Or, you could create a `.iso` (CD image file) and have vbox boot the VM from that. That's how you do a linux install in the VM. So, there are programs/guides to create such an image

Comment: @CraigEstey, I have just noticed, by using some IMG to ISO converters without success, that my file might be corrupted or incorrectly formatted. Thank you, this question is going to be archived until new information is achieved

Answer (score 1):

For UEFI to boot an executable file on USB flash, you need:

- either "MBR partitions" or GPT on the USB flash; with one partition formatted as a FAT file system. This partition probably also needs to be marked as "EFI System Partition" in the partition table (the UEFI specs aren't very clear but it makes sense to me).
- the file you want executed must be in a specific directory and have a specific name that depends on what the platform is (e.g. "`\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.EFI`" for 64-bit 80x86)
- the "Machine Type" field in the executable's PE header must match the name it was given (e.g. `0x8664` for 64-bit 80x86).

The other restriction is that you either need to make sure SecureBoot is turned off in UEFI's settings; or figure out how to digitally sign your executable with a key that the firmware accepts.

Note that the rules for removable media (e.g. USB flash) are different than the rules for fixed media (e.g. internal SATA drives).

Comment: is it compulsory to only have the directories you mentioned, or am I allowed to locate other arbitrary stuff in the, let us say, the EFI folder?

Comment: @Vyber90: You only need to give your boot loader the right name/location (so UEFI can find it). For everything else you can do what you like, but I'd recommend not using the UEFI system partition because FAT is awful (for limitations/restrictions, features, security, ...).